# What happen to TCP connection when user changes network

Tags: networking, tcp, subnet

User 1 is connected to a TCP/IP server(in different subnet) from a wireless access point A.

1. what will happen to TCP/IP connection when User 1 will move to another wireless access point B in same network.
2. What will happen to TCP/IP connection when User 1 will move to another access point X of another subnet network.

Comment: "_User 1 is connected to a TCP/IP server..._: There is no such thing as a server to IP or TCP, so the idea of a TCP/IP server is not realistic. Clients and servers are an application concept.

Comment: Here I mean the connection is TCP connection between client and server.

Comment: TCP doesn't have connections between clients and servers. TCP connects peers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Provided the interruption is short, your connection will survive because you'll keep your IP address.  The interruption includes time for access points and router to update ARP tables.  If this happens quickly enough, the TCP protocol won't notice.
2. Your connection will die, because you'll have a new IP address after the switch.